# Create a foreign key for a django model with specialized accessors

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'd like workers to be able to supervise other workers. A worker does not need a supervisor. They cannot supervise themself. (I don't care about loops)

I'm not sure about the most django standard way to go about this. I can create a custom setter function, but I notice that the model still has `supervisor` and `supervisor_id`, which can be written to directly, circumventing the requirements I have in place.

Here's what I have, but it's telling me "AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'setter'"

```
class Worker(models.Model):
    supervisor = models.ForeignKey(Worker, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @supervisor.setter
    def assign_supervisor(self, s_id):
        if s_id == self.id:
            raise Error("can't supervise yourself!")
        self.supervisor_id = s_id
        self.save()
```

Comment: Have you got a form for this model? In django you'd do this type of validation on the form, or by overriding the `save` on the model itself.

Comment: You could add a `CheckConstraint` to your model to perform this validation at the DB layer, although this doesn't give you a custom "setter" https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/constraints/#checkconstraint